# How do Windows NT-based operating systems address devices?

Tags: windows

I'm confused with notation like

```
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\...
```

and

```
\Device\HardDisk1\DR1
\Device\Video0
```

I see these addresses only in the context of Windows NT-based operating systems such as Windows XP and Windows 7.  What do these addresses mean and how are they used to refer to devices such as hard disks, graphics adapters, human interface devices (keyboards, mice, etc.), network adapters, and other hardware?

Comment: Where and how do you plan on refering to them?

Comment: Sometimes, I get messages that refer to devices using these names.  What I want to understand is what these addresses mean, how other devices are addressed using these notations, and how this may be used by applications to access hardware directly (if possible).

Comment: Linux uses `/dev` nodes to allow direct access to hardware.  What I want to understand is what looks like a similar mechanism to address and access hardware under Windows.

Comment: Since Windows NT, to the best of my knowledge, Windows does not allow you to directly access hardware. That is how it protects itself. With Windows 95/98/ME, any programmer could, and it allowed them to make the OS unstable. The solution was to make everything go through the kernel, and let it decide if it was safe to execute. If not, it could throw an error, but protect itself from bad programming...at least to a greater degree.

Comment: @KCotreau: That's true, but irrelevant. You now have to ask the kernel. But if harddisks didn't have names such as these, you couldn't ask the kernel at all. It wouldn't know which harddisk you are talking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, the Windows kernel *does* have a rooted file ("file") system. In *nix, the root is `/`, and in Windows it's `\`. The Win32 subsystem doesn't expose it, though. You can explore it with [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657).

Some (possibly familiar) NT device names (`M` and `N` are just integers):

- `\Device\HarddiskM\DRN`: Disks
- `\Device\HarddiskVolumeN`: Partitions
- `\Device\CdRomN`: Optical disc drives
- `\Device\KeyboardClassN`: Keyboards
- `\Device\MountPointManager`: Not a device, but keeps track of storage devices
- `\Device\Null`: Eats up data and outputs nulls (zeroes)

`\Device\HardDisk1\DR1` is the *true* name of the disk *to Windows*, and `multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)` is legacy -- it has nothing to do with how *Windows* refers to devices, but how the **boot loader** refers to the disk. How it works, I have no idea ([this page explains parts of it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977184.aspx)), but it's not really something Windows concerns itself with after it starts booting.

Newer versions of Windows use the Boot Configuration Data (BCD), which is a file named `BCD` whose format is like that of the registry, instead of `Boot.ini`. It generally uses unique identifiers (GUIDs) to refer to volumes instead of drive letters or file system paths, and it's what newer versions of Windows use.

Comment: What about hardware other than storage devices (such as `\Device\Video0`)?

Comment: @DragonLord: ... what about it? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: What names are used to refer to keyboards, mice, network adapters, and other devices?

Comment: @DragonLord: Good point, I'll add that. I just focused on boot loading, didn't notice the question was more general.

Comment: The "rooted file system" you mentioned is called the [Object Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_(Windows)) namespace. I found this after clicking through the WinObj link and doing some research.  It's quite intriguing how Windows NT works on the inside...

Comment: @DragonLord: Indeed. NT is really amazing/awesome on the inside, but Win32 hides it to a large extent, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Do you know if there is a relation/mapping to the [device listed in the Event Log](http://superuser.com/questions/600525/)?

Answer (score 1):

The first line, which has been rendered obsolete by the BCD (Boot Configuration Data store) in Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Server 2008, is from a boot.ini file for Windows XP or Server 2003, and is located in the root directory of the system drive. That tells Windows where to go (what disk and partition) to find the system files it needs to boot.

Look [here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsNT/AdminTips/Booting/PurposeoftheBOOT.INIFile.html) for a detailed explanation of "multi" and "rdisk". The rest means that look at disk 0 (they start at 0 and move up from there, and you can see their numbers in the disk manager), partition 1 (unlike the disks, these start being numbered at 1 and go up).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102873

As far as the enumeration of devices goes, it is a very complicated programming subject, which is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want your head to explode. The format you gave is how the device is addressed as a hardware ID in the registry.

As a practical matter you can look at this registry key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum

to match any error you may get to a "hardware ID" value in one of the sub keys to determine exactly what device the error may refer to.

Comment: Section 4.2.7 of the _Advanced RISC Computing Specification_, [republished here by the NetBSD Foundation](http://netbsd.org/docs/Hardware/Machines/ARC/riscspec.pdf), tells one everything about ARC paths.