# "Windows detected a hard drive" issue in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I upgraded to the OCZ-Agility3 120GB from a 60 OCZ Vertex2 SSD.  I cloned the drive from the Vertex to the new Agility.  Everything seemed to have gone well and have not had any problems.

Recently in the passed month I have gotten this error:

[image: Error message]

I downloaded teh OCZToolboxMP and ran the SMART utility and don't see anything wrong:

SMART READ DATA

```
ModelNumber : OCZ-AGILITY3        
Serial Number   : OCZ-Y1945X77438P4NU6
WWN     : 5-e8-3a-97 ebea5ba76

Revision: 10
Attributes List
  1: SSD Raw Read Error Rate                Normalized Rate:  70 total ECC and RAISE errors
  5: SSD Retired Block Count                Reserve blocks remaining: 100%
  9: SSD Power-On Hours                     Total hours power on: 968
 12: SSD Power Cycle Count                  Count of power on/off cycles: 28
171: SSD Program Fail Count                 Total number of Flash program operation failures: 0
172: SSD Erase Fail Count                   Total number of Flash erase operation failures: 0
174: SSD Unexpected power loss count        Total number of unexpected power loss: 11
177: SSD Wear Range Delta                   Delta between most-worn and least-worn Flash blocks: 0
181: SSD Program Fail Count                 Total number of Flash program operation failures: 0
182: SSD Erase Fail Count                   Total number of Flash erase operation failures: 0
187: SSD Reported Uncorrectable Errors      Uncorrectable RAISE errors reported to the host for all data access: 4145
194: SSD Temperature Monitoring             Current: 30  High: 30 Low: 30
195: SSD ECC On-the-fly Count               Normalized Rate: 120 
196: SSD Reallocation Event Count           Total number of reallocated Flash blocks: 100
201: SSD Uncorrectable Soft Read Error Rate Normalized Rate: 120
204: SSD Soft ECC Correction Rate (RAISE)   Normalized Rate: 120
230: SSD Life Curve Status                  Current state of drive operation based upon the Life Curve: 100
231: SSD Life Left                          Approximate SDD life Remaining: 100%
241: SSD Lifetime writes from host          lifetime writes 893 GB
242: SSD Lifetime reads from host           lifetime reads 968 GB
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what might be wrong and or how I can go about fixing this?  Please let me know if there is other information I can provide.  Thanks for your help

Windows 7 x64 SP1
AMD Phenom II X4 940
8GB RAM

Comment: Is there any messages in the event log?

Comment: My experience is that if Windows actually manages to detect a potentially fatal drive problem, then you probably do have a drive problem.

Comment: Here is what I see in event log:

The driver has detected that device \Device\Harddisk2\DR2 has predicted that it will fail. Immediately back up your data and replace your hard disk drive. A failure may be imminent.

Comment: Windows Disk Diagnostic detected a S.M.A.R.T fault on disk OCZ-AGILITY3 ATA Device (volumes C:\).This disk might fail;back up your computer now.All data on the hard disk, including files, documents, pictures, programs, and settings might be lost if your hard disk fails.  To determine if the hard disk needs to be repaired or replaced, contact the manufacturer of your computer.  If you can't back up (for example, you have no CDs or other backup media), you should shut down your computer and restart when you have backup media available.In the meantime, do not save any critical files to this disk.

Answer (score 1):

> Uncorrectable RAISE errors reported to the host for all data access: 4145
>   Total number of reallocated Flash blocks: 100

Needs to be 0. You have a bad SSD.

Answer (score 0):

[DR means "drive removable"](https://superuser.com/questions/357891/how-do-i-determine-which-hd-is-involved-in-the-event-viewer/357904#357904), 2 is the USB host controller ID assigned by Windows. So it is not your System drive that has problems but a removable drive you are attaching via USB.

Each usb port will be assigned a different number when being used, sorting out which is which is difficult.

Comment: Hmm the weird thing is I don't have any USB removable drives, all my drives are SATA

Comment: Strange indeed.