# what physical disk is referenced by Event 7, Disk error "The device, \Device\Harddisk2\DR2, has a bad block."

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008, event-viewer, bad-blocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine which HD is involved in the Event Viewer?](https://superuser.com/questions/357891/how-do-i-determine-which-hd-is-involved-in-the-event-viewer)

***NOT a duplicate***

well, maybe the general premise is a duplicate, but the linked question is not answered, only has 1 answer (by the closer, yesterday) regarding USB drives, is old, and my question has more technical information.

*more "not a duplicate" details*

1) I do not have any USB drives attached, thus the answer in [How do I determine which HD is involved in the Event Viewer?](https://superuser.com/questions/357891/how-do-i-determine-which-hd-is-involved-in-the-event-viewer) is not related.

2) the answer in [How do I determine which HD is involved in the Event Viewer?](https://superuser.com/questions/357891/how-do-i-determine-which-hd-is-involved-in-the-event-viewer) ***does NOT say how to determine what physical drive is which***, especially after I gave info in my comments  (drive2 != channel 0, target 1)

so, not sure how to reopen this (maybe i can not) but again, **this is not a duplicate.  my question was not already answered.**

=====================================

**spec details:**

Running Windows 2008 R2 server.

I have 5 physical disks in my system.

4 2TB disks are setup in a raid 5 (software) configuration, 1 320GB disk with the OS

**question details:**

When doing the initial disk sync of my Raid 5, I got this Disk Event 7 come up.   Unfortunatly in Disk Manager I saw yellow exclamations on two disks (not just one) and so am uncertain which disk is actually the one mentioned by this message.

Does anyone know how to find out which physical disk is referenced as "\Device\Harddisk2\DR2"?

The only info I found on microsoft's site was about Win2000/NT, and the info they give does not work in Win2k8.

Comment: fyi, Windows Device Manager shows disk information in the following format:   "Disk 3:   Location 1 (Channel 0, Target 1, Lun 0)"   which means "Disk X" does not relate to the SATA channel, etc.

Comment: more details: the OS drive is a PATA,  the raid drives are SATA2