# How to identify drive device from event log (Harddisk#\DR#)?

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive, event-log, event-viewer

I have a messages about drive errors in the Windows Event log, like this:

> Bad Block On Device \Device\Harddisk0\DR0

I have two hard drives in the system. How can I know which one causes these errors? I see nowhere the same identification type, like there.

For example, the following are dialogs from Device Manager:

[image: screenshots of Device Manager]

Can I be sure it is drive `C` since it is "Disk 0"?

Comment: Click the last tab where you will see detailed information about the device, including the mount point (`\Device\HardDisk0\...` etc.). You will also see things like the device ID and other manufacturer data.

Comment: "DiskX" refers to a physical device. "Drive C:" refers to a "logical drive" AKA "file system" AKA "volume" in Windows, which is an entirely different concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can be certain that the error message `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0` is referencing Disk 0 as listed in the Disk Management MMC (**Run** > `diskmgmt.msc`). The **Harddisk#** syntax always refers to the disk number, but keep in mind this will be the disk number involved in the error message *at the time the error was logged*. If for any reason the offending disk's number changes between the time of the error and when you review Device Manager, you would blame the wrong disk.

Answer (score 9):

The Harddisk# and DR# number both refer to a Drive (not a Partition or Volume)

- this is normally a physical drive (HDD, SSD, USB)
- each Drive may contain multiple partitions each of which may have a drive letter

As stated the Harddisk# item matches the Disk# id shown by Windows Disk Management.

The numbers are allocated in real time as disks are detected or connected.

For internal HDDs, both the Harddisk# and DR# number normally remain fixed (unless you swap motherboard socket connections).

Harddisk# numbers for removable drives (flashdrives and USB drives):

- the next available number is allocated during connection (filling gaps if present)
- if a drive is disconnected the number is removed leaving a gap
- once a drive is disconnected there is no record of previously allocated numbers

The DR# number is also dynamically allocated but follows different rules:

- numbers are allocated sequentially and are not reused while Windows is booted
- each time a removable drive is disconnected and reconnected the DR# number increments

Initially the Harddisk# and DR# number will match:

- but active use of removable drives causes the DR# numbers to rise
- only when Windows restarts does the DR# number allocation get reset
- the DR# number is not reset during User Logoff events only at a Windows Restart

Once disconnected there is no way to tie a DR# number to a physical device. A removable drive may have been allocated many different DR# numbers in the past.