Which hard disk is reporting bad blocks?
System: Dell Precision 3660 tower with primary drive 512 GB SSD and two 4TB HDD drives configured in Intel software RAID 1.
ONLY on reboot, the system dumps about 30 identical error messages into the Windows System event log:
"The device, device\Harddisk1\DR1, has a bad block"
Screenshot:

I'm not sure how to determine which disk it's referring to.
In Computer Management, we have the following:

Does this error report on the same disk numbers as listed in Computer Management?
In DISKPART, we have the following:

And the partitions and volumes as follows:



The Intel Optane status window reports that all drives are normal:

And so does Crystal Disk Info:

I would be very grateful for assistance to determine definitely which disk is being referred to by this error message, so I can drill down into additional diagnostics.

@Ramhound this answer is based on what? can you teach me how to determine that the NVMe SSD is the culprit?  Thanks.

@John Yes the vendor diagnostics will be run soon, but we can't take the machine offline right now.  Was hoping for more details with the tools available within Windows.

@Ramhound so my concern was whether the numbering scheme of \Device\Harddisk1 matches the diskpart partitions.  Sometimes those numbers don't align, and a 0 == 1 or such.  So you are saying diskpart and the event log both use the same drive numbering scheme, so \Device\Harddisk1 == diskpart Disk 1?

You could do a chkdsk /r c:  and later a chkdsk /r d:  and then it would report which drive letter has bad blocks.  However, since you have a RAID that still isn't enough to identify which RAID member.

https://superuser.com/questions/831297/how-to-identify-drive-device-from-event-log-harddisk-dr
