# Identifying Windows 10 \Device\Harddisk1\DR2

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, event-log, event-viewer

I'm getting errors in Windows 10's event log stating \Device\Harddisk1\DR2 drive controller is having a problem. I know that the hard disk numbers depend on the BIOS and do not match the physical connections.

How can I tell which physical device this actually is? diskpart lists these devices:

```
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online         1863 GB   927 GB
```

Is \Device\Harddisk1 the "Disk 1" listed here? Is there some other way to determine what Windows 10 means by Harddisk1 ?

What is DR2?

Comment: Yes, it means Disk 1, Windows starts counting at 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine which HD is involved in the Event Viewer?](http://superuser.com/questions/357891/how-do-i-determine-which-hd-is-involved-in-the-event-viewer)

Comment: @Ramhound I know windows starts counting at zero, but that Window's "zero" depends on the order that BIOS reports and often does not match physical device ports or location.

Comment: @user1663987 - Your question does not make it clear you knew that.  I thought you needed help identify it, knowing Windows starts counting at 0, helps you do exactly that.  What BIOS does is outside of the scope of this question, Windows is generating the error, so what Windows does is really the only thing that is important.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, my question asks first how to identify the physical device that windows is calling Harddisk1. If I can identify that the disk numbers that diskpart shows match those in the eventlog, I can at least guess at the disk.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 that page mostly leads to an explanation of what it is, but leaves open the original questions of how to actually identify which disk it actually refers to

Comment: @user1663987 It's still the same question, so it's a duplicate (IMO anyway), even if the (current) answers aren't helpful. But hey, takes more than just my vote. ;)

Comment: Which is the reason I indicated in my comment which disk it was.  I just wanted to make it clear, that Windows starts counting at 0, which is the reason you have `Disk 0` and `Disk 1`.  *What "DR2" means is answered in the duplicate.*

Comment: DR stands for Drive Removable, so it is a removable drive , not a fixed drive.

Comment: @Moab Does it? This is based on a source which is plain wrong about the nature of this number – see https://superuser.com/questions/357891/how-do-i-determine-which-hd-is-involved-in-the-event-viewer#comment2798879_357904. More like **D**isk **R**econnected counter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### How can I tell which physical device this actually is?

You can use `wmic diskdrive get caption, deviceid, size` to match up the devices shown with physical disks.

Example output from my laptop:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online           59 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online         2794 GB  7168 KB
```

And:

```
F:\test>wmic diskdrive get caption, deviceid, size
Caption                            DeviceID            Size
WDC WD5000LPVX-08V0TT5             \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  500105249280
SanDisk Cruzer USB Device          \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  64009128960
Seagate Expansion Desk USB Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  3000582144000
```

As you can see from the deviceid, and confirmed by the sizes, the devices are listed in the same order on my Laptop.

Note:

- The OP has stated that the `wmic` on his PC lists the devices in the **reverse** order. The information still allows the disks to be identified.

Comment: Thank you. The second command lists them in reverse order from the first, but this tells me for sure which is which.

Comment: @user1663987 Interesting. I wonder why yours are reversed compared to mine?

Comment: Thanks. On 1809 got "Invalid Get Expression": `wmic --% diskdrive get caption, deviceid, size` gets there.

Comment: The working command for PowerShell and Command with Administrator permission are different.

@LaurieStearn Your comments exactly right for PowerShell. but not for Command window.
In command windows as administator, works with "wmic diskdrive get caption, deviceid, size" but not yours.

Interesting things, commands are difference between PowerSheel and  Command with Administrator permission.