# Which drive is \Device\Harddisk1\DR1?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8, disk-controller

While I was trying to find out why the main disk is performing a form of unexpained "thrashing"(while there was  no RAM issue), freezing up apps temporarily, I found a relevant error in the logs:

"The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk1\DR1"

and I'm trying to find which drive it is.

However, from device manager and disk management, the main disk is "0" and there are informational mentions in the logs of dr0 when I enable/disable write caching so it does recognize 0 as different from dr1.

However, the computer has no other disk that I know of and if I open it up while it does have a space for it (laptop), it has no connections for a new one.

I wonder if it's a 'hidden' device of some sort or a problem with the manufacturer's blocking of connections.

In any case I'd like to find out which that device is precisely.

On device manager, DVD drive is mentioned as 'CD ROM 0" when I use 'Populate' in the Volumes tab of its properties and similarly HDD reports disk 0. I still wonder though if for some reason the dvd drive is considered as disk 1 but there's no confirmation of it anywhere. Any other devices such as USB drives etc. are shown as 2, 3, 4 etc. on drive management.

Also looking in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE I can only see HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi\Scsi Port 0\Scsi Bus 0\Target Id 0\Logical Unit Id 0 as PhysicalDrive2 which is a bit weird now that I think of it. That location also confirms the model of the main known drive.

When changing write caching settings \Device\Harddisk0\DR0 is reported on logs (as an information of the change) so \Device\Harddisk0\DR0 is considered by the system different from \Device\Harddisk1\DR1.

Comment: If you open the properties of a drive in device manager, the object path will be listed under "Physical Device Object name" in the details tab.

Comment: Could it just be semantics and inconsistency with Microsoft naming convention for devices that is confusing you? disk 0 in some instances will be the first hard drive, while DR1 is the first hard drive in other situations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Windows NT-based operating systems address devices?](http://superuser.com/questions/307955/how-do-windows-nt-based-operating-systems-address-devices)

Comment: Related question: StackOverflow, 2013-08-29: [*How do I map the device details such as \Device\Harddisk1\DR1 in the event log to a drive letter such as C:?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509633/how-do-i-map-the-device-details-such-as-device-harddisk1-dr1-in-the-event-log-t)

Comment: None of the suggestions worked. perhaps because these methods do not work with virtual drives.

Comment: For anyone finding their way here and confused because the `HardDisk#` is higher than the number of hard-drives/SSDs they have installed, it might just be an empty memory-card reader. I get this spurious error if I boot up with no card in the reader and I don't get it if there is a card in it. It's dumb and terrible design and shouldn't be happening, but what do you expect?  I haven't tested, but I suspect floppy-drives (USB or not) and other removable drives (technically not removable drives, removable *media*) might also cause the same error. 

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Run the following PowerShell command as Administrator:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | Select -Prop DeviceId,FriendlyName,SerialNumber
```

This will show output like:

```
DeviceId FriendlyName              SerialNumber
-------- ------------              ------------
1        ST1000DM003-9YN162        S1D2RPMB
5        ST1000DM003-1CH162        Z1D3CPP3
2        ST1000DM003-9YN162        S1D34BYN
0        Corsair Force LS SSD      144381700001017402C2
4        WDC WD10EFRX-68PJCN0      WD-WCC4J9CC8112
3        Samsung SSD 950 PRO 256GB 0025_3853_61B0_3DD0.
```

The `DeviceId` corresponds to the `N` in the `\Device\HardDiskN` path.

This command is useful when you are using Storage Spaces, which can prevent the physical disks from appearing in the tools referenced in the other answers, like DiskPart.

Comment: I get the error :The term 'get-physicaldisk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Chec
k the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:17
+ get-physicaldisk <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-physicaldisk:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You lack "the Get-PhysicalDisk cmdlet". https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-physicaldisk?view=win10-ps (But where is it or how do I get it? What does it come with?)

Answer (score 10):

This "dd" utility worked for me.  But it **must be run as administrator** to include the */Harddisk/DRx mappings!

```
 dd --list  <--- as administrator
```

It provides a report that allows tracing between the various naming schemes and includes the DRn types.

http://www.chrysocome.net/dd

The mappings is not completely obvious but if one assumes that the NT Block Device Objects are listed in order I think the correct drive can be inferred.

If you have unique drive sizes, it is simple since the report directly shows the size for each DRn.

***Update 1/23/2015:***  Adding sample output. This system just has one physical 512GB drive with 6 partitions and a CDRom.

```
rawwrite dd for windows version 0.5.
Written by John Newbigin <jn@it.swin.edu.au>
This program is covered by the GPL.  See copying.txt for details
Win32 Available Volume Information
\\.\Volume{a502c160-1241-4338-a345-b76f4a973d9f}\
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume5
  fixed media
  Mounted on \\.\c:

\\.\Volume{c8a5d58a-7083-440b-a5c1-e262ca3a9d7d}\
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume6
  fixed media
  Mounted on \\.\g:

\\.\Volume{9d1b0246-5f39-4ef8-9016-ef83d03d7255}\
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume4
  fixed media
  Mounted on \\.\x:

\\.\Volume{4ca2b56b-0778-4a61-8979-6ad9fa1df45f}\
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume7
  fixed media
  Mounted on \\.\y:

\\.\Volume{d20ed74c-0607-11e4-8256-8086f2c4e4ff}\
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume8
  removeable media
  Mounted on \\.\e:

\\.\Volume{570d1087-e7b4-11e3-824c-806e6f6e6963}\
  link to \\?\Device\CdRom0
  CD-ROM
  Mounted on \\.\d:

\\.\Volume{d20edf99-0607-11e4-8256-8086f2c4e4ff}\
  link to \\?\Device\ClvtDrv0
  CD-ROM
  Mounted on \\.\s:
```

***(This section is only present when run as admin)***

```
NT Block Device Objects
\\?\Device\CdRom0
  size is 2147483647 bytes
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition0
  link to \\?\Device\Harddisk0\DR0         <--------------------------- DR0
  Fixed hard disk media. Block size = 512
  size is 512110190592 bytes
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume1
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume2
  Fixed hard disk media. Block size = 512
  size is 41943040 bytes
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition3
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume3
  Fixed hard disk media. Block size = 512
  size is 134217728 bytes
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition4
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume4
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition5
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume5
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition6
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume6
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition7
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume7
\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0
  link to \\?\Device\Harddisk1\DR1
\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition1
  link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume8

Virtual input devices
 /dev/zero   (null data)
 /dev/random (pseudo-random data)
 -           (standard input)

Virtual output devices
 -           (standard output)
```

**Added by barlop**
I will just include a pic that illustrates somewhat [image]

Comment: @crokusek is this the same DD for cygwin? I get 'unknown option' when I try to use the `--list` parameter.

Comment: It may not be, I downloaded it directly from [http://www.chrysocome.net/dd](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd).

Comment: "`'dd' is not recognized as an internal or external command`..."

Answer (score 7):

This can be found in Sysinternals WinObj tool (run as Admin):

1. open in the tree: {Device\Harddisk[N]}.
2. note volumes mapping above and then re-check in {GLOBAL??"}: sort by SymLink column and see there which \Device\HarddiskVolume[N] maps to which disk letter.

Comment: Still not properly associated. In my Event Viewer I have a Harddisk3\DR3 error, in WinObj I have neither Harddisk3 nor a DR3 under any of them.

Comment: It is easy and nice solution even though use a external tool WinObj from Sysinternals.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this as administrator:

```
C:\windows\system32>diskpart

    Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
    Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
    On computer: COMPUTERNAME

    DISKPART> list disk

      Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
      --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
      Disk 0    Online          476 GB    11 GB
      Disk 1    Online           59 GB      0 B

    DISKPART> sel disk 1

    Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

    DISKPART> list part

      Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
      -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
    * Partition 1    Primary             59 GB      0 B
```

Comment: `echo list disk | diskpart`

Answer (score 1):

I was hunting for \device\harddisk1\dr2

This will be the 2nd disk listed in diskpart:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          476 GB  3072 KB
  Disk 1    Online         2794 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online         2794 GB  7168 KB
  Disk 3    Online         3726 GB  7168 KB
DISKPART> sel disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> detail disk

WD My Book 1130 USB Device
Disk ID: 0002DCC8
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 3     H                       Partition   2794 GB  Healthy
```

Notice "WD My Book 1130 USB Device" and the "H" under Ltr.
**\device\harddisk1\dr2 is drive H.**

Answer (score 0):

The [recommended Microsoft way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/159865) is to:

- launch **diskmgmt.msc**
- Right click *gray portion of the basic or dynamic disk whose disk number matches the "Harddisk#" in the error message*
- click properties

You now have the properties opened of the device displaying identifying information.

Props goes to **lazy256** for finding this link

Answer (score -1):

In according https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/159865 please see:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Hardware\Devicemap\Atdisk *(for IDE-based devices)*
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Hardware\Devicemap\SCSI   *(for Atapi-compliant or SCSI devices)*