# The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk1\DR3: which disk corresponds in Computer Management?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hardware-failure, chkdsk

[image: The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk1\DR3.]

In Windows 10 64-bit, I went to Event Viewer saw this error:

`The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk1\DR3`

I looked in Computer Management > Disk Management, but not sure which drive the error message refers to.

I would run a `chkdsk /r` on all the drives, but this 5TB drive would take over 3 days to complete a `chkdsk /r`. If indeed this external caused the error message, I want to make sure.

[image]

Comment: It clearly says which disk it is. \Device\Harddisk **1** \DR3, so it is referring to Disk 1.

Comment: What is dr3 for then? So it is my 931GB drive?

Comment: Its somekind of identification to which partition it is referring. And yes, it appears to be your 931GB drive. A controller error is not like bad sectors though. Chkdsk may make the drive become permanently unavailable. you should take this warning and start doing backups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which drive is \Device\Harddisk1\DR1?](http://superuser.com/questions/538574/which-drive-is-device-harddisk1-dr1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine which HD is involved in the Event Viewer?](https://superuser.com/questions/357891/how-do-i-determine-which-hd-is-involved-in-the-event-viewer)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the disk number as displayed in Disk Management. Alternatively, there are many ways to check it on command line.

- PowerShell:

  ```
  Get-PhysicalDisk | Select DeviceId, Model, SerialNumber
  ```

  ```
  "list disk" | diskpart
  ```
- cmd.exe:

  ```
  echo list disk | diskpart
  ```
- any command interpreter:

  ```
  wmic diskdrive get Index, DeviceId, Model, SerialNumber
  ```

Commands using `diskpart` need to be run in a terminal launched as Administrator.

Answer (score -1):

It clearly says which disk it is. \Device\Harddisk **1** \DR3, so it is referring to Disk 1.

The DR3 part at the end is some kind of identifaction to which partition it is referring.

Do note, a controller error is not like bad sectors though. Chkdsk may make the drive become permanently unavailable. You should take this warning and start doing backups.

Comment: `DR` part has nothing to do with partitions. Basically, it is the disk reconnection counter – https://superuser.com/a/1268208