# What is the trailing "\D" in Windows Event Log disk error details?

Tags: event-log

Sometimes in the Windows Event Log you may see an error or warning about disk problems regarding something like:

```
\Device\Harddisk0\D.
```

Presumably, the Harddisk0 refers to the first physical drive as reported by the *Disk Management* MMC snap-in (though I have personally never seen anything other than disk 0 being reported even with different drives and even when the drive in question was definitely a different one—like the SD card in the card-reader).

**But what is the `D`?**

It definitely isn’t a partition. Physical problems affect the whole drive, not a single volume, plus the `System\Disk` event log entries logs physical problems; filesystem issues are logged to `Application\Winlogon`.

So what does the `D` refer to? Has anyone ever seen a different letter? Googling for `\Device\Harddisk0\C` returns a small handful of results which are most likely just a typos. I managed to find [one person who asked this](http://www.hardwareanalysis.com/content/topic/12946/?o=40#229789) question but got no answer.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/307955/how-do-windows-nt-based-operating-systems-address-devices

Comment: I think that may be related, but it doesn’t look like it’s the same thing.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0`? Maybe the code reporting the error had a bug and chopped off the last two letters...

Comment: @Mehrdad, No, it’s *always* `\D`, this weekend with the SD card, last year with an old Maxtor, every time I’ve ever seen that warning, it’s always `Harddisk0\D` (even the number never varies).

Answer (score 0):

Use WinObj [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

\Device\Harddisk0\D

That is, in this case, the problem entirely with HDD. Harddisk0.

[Windows DDK 2003 SP1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/0/f/90f019ac-8243-48d3-91cf-81fc4093ecfd/1830_usa_ddk.iso) ISO (230 MB) 3790.1830, objdir.exe:

```
objdir \GLOBAL?? | find /I "harddisk" | more
```

Get device info:

```
wmic DISKDRIVE get Caption, DeviceID, Index, PNPDeviceID, Partitions, SCSIPort, Size
```

Output:

```
Caption              DeviceID            Index  Partitions  PNPDeviceID                                                                                        SCSIPort  Size
SAMSUNG HD501LJ      \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE4  4      1           IDE\DISKSAMSUNG_HD501LJ_________________________CR100-13\3053554D314A5143304236343639202020202020  5         500105249280
ST31500341AS         \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  0      1           IDE\DISKST31500341AS____________________________CC1H____\6&162587C5&0&0.0.0                        1         1500299297280
ST32000542AS         \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  1      2           IDE\DISKST32000542AS____________________________CC34____\5&5C6CFD6&0&0.0.0                         2         2000396321280
WDC WD5000KS-00MNB0  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3  3      1           IDE\DISKWDC_WD5000KS-00MNB0_____________________07.02E07\5&1841A32E&0&0.0.0                        4         500105249280
WDC WD5000KS-00MNB0  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  2      2           IDE\DISKWDC_WD5000KS-00MNB0_____________________07.02E07\5&2AFB53D3&0&0.0.0                        3         500106332160
```

## `D` is shorter alias `DRx`.

[image: WinObj]

Symbolink \Device\HarddiskX\ - unique.

[image: winObj]

Comment: I don’t think that’s the same thing; I see nothing ending in `\D`. Can you figure out if there is some sort of mapping or something?

Comment: `D is shorter alias DRx.`   Actually it’s not, `DR`—supposedly—means removable drive.

Comment: @Synetech Well I have all the hard drives and removable), at least for now) I'll go look in the pantry). `DR` - Hard Drives. It real screen WinObj at my system.

Comment: I’m inclined to believe that Moab has a reason to [say that](http://superuser.com/a/357904/3279). `:-\` I’d guess that `\D` means “drive”, but that doesn’t mean much since there are so many types (~5 or 6 from what I remember).