# Can I create a shortcut which points to a specific drive regardless of its drive letter?

Tags: windows, junction, file-shortcut, reparse-points

I noticed that I cannot use `\\?\Volume{f993747a-5d7a-4de1-a97a-c20c1af1ba02}\path\to\target` or `\Device\HarddiskVolume5\path\to\target` as shortcut targets—it won't work. It only works when I use drive letters in absolute paths. I don't want to use drive letters or relative paths.

Can I specify a target for a shortcut which won't break when drive letters change? Alternatively, can I create an NTFS reparse point (such as a junction point) to do this?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: You mean there are no alternatives that can best accomplish the goal, not even programmatically nor can you offer me a best practice that best accomplishes it?

Comment: By definition you cannot do what you want to do.

Comment: I'm sure someone could write a program to repair broken links but to my knowledge, no one has . But that would still be a possibility. I'm sure it's possible, maybe impractical.

Comment: "I don't want to use drive letters or relative paths" -- is not possible.

Comment: "I wanna be able to specify a target that won't break the shortcut when drive letters change." is not possible.

Comment: "write a program to repair broken links" is so impractical it's impossible  -- how would you know where the target of the broken link has has moved to (target could be a URL whch could be anywhere in cyberspace)?

Comment: Rather than reposting nearly identical questions, it would be much better if you would edit your question to be clearer.  Too many deleted questions risks hitting one of the system controls that will either limit or restrict you from posting further questions.  If you feel that your earlier questions were low quality, then the "improve" or "edit" button underneath the question would have enabled you to make them better questions.

Comment: The best thing I can think of to accomplish my goal is a symbolic link that points to a drive letter, such that when drive letter changes I can point the link to the new drive letter. Or maybe a network drive that maps to a drive letter. Those wouldn't have been a bad suggestions, although I'd prefer something more robust but those would have been decent answers.

Comment: @Mokubai I deleted the second question because it was marked as a duplicate. I deleted my first question, because it was an all around bad question and no one was reading it anymore because it was old. I had to rephrase this one otherwise it would have been marked as a duplicate of my second question.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/307955/how-do-windows-nt-based-operating-systems-address-devices

Comment: @DragonLord I'm familiar with this notation but it doesnt appear you can use these notations when specifying shortcut targets.

Comment: Why would a drive letter change (unless you are using removable media)?

Comment: @LDC3 I manage a couple dozen drives and they get automounted and I'd rather not keep track of them.

Comment: When the drives get mounted, can they execute a batch file from the drive? The batch file could set an environment variable which is used to set the link (or path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Can I create a shortcut which points to a specific drive regardless of its drive letter?

> I don't want to use drive letters or relative paths

The type of targets you wish to use (`\?\Volume{f993747a-5d7a-4de1-a97a-c20c1af1ba02}\path\to\target` or `\Device\HarddiskVolume5\path\to\target`) are not valid targets for a shortcut.

All of the valid targets for shortcuts must use one of the types specifed below.

---

> Shortcut preference items allow you to configure a shortcut to a file system object (such as a file, folder, drive, share, or computer), a shell object (such as a printer, desktop item, or control panel item), or a URL (such as a Web page or an FTP site).

Source [Configure a Shortcut Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753580.aspx)

---

#### Alternatively, can I create an NTFS reparse point (such as a junction point) to do this?

You can use [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) to create a symbolic link of the form `\\?\Volume{f993747a-5d7a-4de1-a97a-c20c1af1ba02}\path\to\target.txt`

```
c:
md \test
cd \test
mklink testlink \\?\Volume{d1a54614-9369-11e4-b7ab-ccaf78b24c0a}\test\test.txt
```

Now the directory test contains a symbolic link (which in my case points to a file `f:\test\test.txt` on an external drive).

```
C:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8D0-DF1E

 Directory of C:\test

29/03/2015  23:24    <DIR>          .
29/03/2015  23:24    <DIR>          ..
29/03/2015  23:17    <SYMLINK>      testlink [\\?\Volume{d1a54614-9369-11e4-b7ab-ccaf78b24c0a}\test\test.txt]
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  248,410,976,256 bytes free
```

...

```
C:\test>type testlink
this file is test.txt
C:\test>
```

...

```
C:\test>type f:\test\test.txt
this file is test.txt
C:\test>
```

Note

- This only works if you try to dereference the link from the command prompt, but not if you try to access it from the explorer interface.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.

Comment: That link talks only about shell shortcuts; how does it apply to filesystem-level symlinks or junctions?

Comment: @DavidPostill Symbolic links or mapped network drives would actually accomplish what I'm looking for. I mean you change the letters on volumes then all you have to do is point the links to another letter. And you can use these links in shortcuts. Although I was hoping for a better solution than these ones, certainly a better one than the suggestion "it is not possible".

Comment: @grawity junctions was added to the question **after** I answered.

Comment: @wes answer updated to give solution using a symbolic link

Comment: [**mountvol**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol) can be used to find out the GUID of the partition, e.g. `mountvol X: /L`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack and possibly insecure, but you should be able to set up sharing on the root folder of the drive of interest (sharename `floatdrive`, say) with appropriate sharing permissions, and then construct all shortcuts/links using networking URL syntax on `localhost`:

```
\\localhost\floatdrive\folder\or\file\of\interest.txt
```

As long as Windows mounts the drive correctly, perhaps the share name will follow the drive no matter what drive letter it's been assigned.  I unfortunately don't have a system on hand at the moment suitable to test this, though.