# Can an NTFS symlink have a volume guid target?

Tags: windows, ntfs

Any way to specify e.g. \\?\Volume{f993747a-5d7a-4de1-a97a-c20c1af1ba02}\path\to\target.txt as the target of a symlink? Or does the absolute path always require a drive letter?

Comment: Sounds like something you can find out by just trying... What stopped you from doing that?

Comment: I did. But I didn't read anywhere that it wasn't possible, so I was wondering if there was some fancy prefix I'm supposed to use or something. Or someone can just tell me if it is or isn't possible and not be a smartass.

Comment: is this not just a dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/895229/can-i-create-a-shortcut-which-points-to-a-specific-drive-regardless-of-its-drive ?

Comment: No because that question only concerns shortcuts not symbolic links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can an NTFS symlink have a volume guid target?

You can use [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) to create a symbolic link of the form `\\?\Volume{f993747a-5d7a-4de1-a97a-c20c1af1ba02}\path\to\target.txt`

```
c:
md \test
cd \test
mklink testlink \\?\Volume{d1a54614-9369-11e4-b7ab-ccaf78b24c0a}\test\test.txt
```

Now the directory test contains a symbolic link (which in my case points to a file `f:\test\test.txt` on an external drive).

```
C:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8D0-DF1E

 Directory of C:\test

29/03/2015  23:24    <DIR>          .
29/03/2015  23:24    <DIR>          ..
29/03/2015  23:17    <SYMLINK>      testlink [\\?\Volume{d1a54614-9369-11e4-b7ab-ccaf78b24c0a}\test\test.txt]
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  248,410,976,256 bytes free
```

...

```
C:\test>type testlink
this file is test.txt
C:\test>
```

...

```
C:\test>type f:\test\test.txt
this file is test.txt
C:\test>
```

Note

- This only works if you try to dereference the link from the command prompt, but not if you try to access it from the explorer interface.

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.

Comment: The link gets created to be sure, but if I try to access it in Windows explorer nothing happens. So I guess the answer is yes only if you try to access it from the command line but no if you try to do it from the UI.

Comment: Unless you find otherwise to my previous comment, I'll modify your answer to state only from the command line and vote it the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed only a single issue after years of using `10,000's` of cross-drive hard links extensively. How significant it is will depend on your specific situation. Note that my application is using hard-links ("directory junctions," created with `linkd.exe`) only, so the following may or may not apply to the other types of symlink.

The only issue I've had is that **chkdsk** behaves badly in rare cases. If `chkdsk.exe` runs automatically on boot in response to a drive being previously shut down with a pending dirty flag, then it seems to remove all the cross-drive junctions in some cases. Besides removing the junctions, however the `chkdsk.exe` bug doesn't corrupt anything.

There are various workarounds and strategies for addressing the `chkdsk.exe` problem, which are beyond the scope of the original question, so suffice it to say that yes it works... with the one caveat I've encountered having been mentioned.